# ASP.NET what reference to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: asp.net

Just getting the following error RNGCryptoServiceProvider Is Not Declared just wondering what reference I need to add ?

Comment: Oh come on! `Imports System.Security.Cryptography`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

namespace is System.Security.Cryptography and its Assembly is  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

[RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

System.Security.Cryptography

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx